# Are Managed Identity token acquisition environment variables available on VM?

Tags: azure-managed-identity

When using Azure Managed Identity in the App Service/Functions, the [endpoint and header are available as environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet#obtaining-tokens-for-azure-resources).

When using Azure Managed Identity in Virtual Machine, the [endpoint is published as the Azure Instance Metadata service (IMDS) (http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token), accessible only from within the VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview).

On a VM, is the endpoint set as an environment variable (MSI_ENDPOINT)?

On a VM, is there an indication whether managed identity is enabled?

Ideally, my code can simply check for that variable. Otherwise, I need to check the variable and make a call to the IMDS.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept it. If no, give the response.

Comment: Any updates? I didn't see anything, solved the problem or not. What I'm doing is to help you solve the problem. Please give the response.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Managed Identity is different between App Service/Functions and VM. As you know, the App Service/Functions use the Managed Identity through the environment variables `MSI_ENDPOINT` and `MSI_SECRET` as it shows [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet#obtaining-tokens-for-azure-resources).

But for VM, it does not set the environment variables, you will get the access token from a server inside the Azure and it cannot access outside. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-token) are ways to get the access token for the VMS.

The indication for the Managed Identity of the VM, I think you can get the VM identity property and it will show you if it enables the Managed Identity and which type is used. For example, I use the Azure CLI and it shows like this:

[image]